# how to easily pass from django views to django-rest-framework views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created a nice Django app, anything worked perfectly. Unfortunely I have now to  QUICKLY migrate everything to django-rest-framework and to a VUE frontend. I'm in "charge" just of the backend side, someone else will write the frontend code.

The problem is that I have really complex Django views and I can't figure out how to change them correctly and easily and, most important, how to test them without a frontend.

Here is an example of my view. I created an app that will search on google for some query and then extract the main text from each link. On the same page where you insert the query will be displayed the first 10 links, if you want to scrape more, you have to go to the next page.

This means that on the same view I have the first QueryForm. If a string is passed the scraping starts, if you want to scrape more, a query_id is passed.

def query_create(request):

```
form = QueryForm(request.POST)
user_p = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
context={'form1':form1}
if request.method == 'POST'  :
        if form.is_valid():
            query_obj = form.save(commit=False)
            query_obj.user = user_p


            query_string=query_obj.query
            search_engine=query_obj.search_engine
            query_obj.save()
            data=multi_scraping.scrape(query_obj.search_dict, 0, 10,query_string)
            queryset=[]
            for index, row in data.iterrows():
                link = Link(scraping_id=str(query_obj),
                            isBlocked=row['isBlocked'],
                            published_Date=row['published'],
                            modified_date=row['update'],
                            language=row['language'],
                            search_engine=row['search_engine'],
                            source=row['source'],
                            source_url=row['source_url'],
                            title=row['title'],
                            transcript=row['transcript'],
                            url=row['url']
                            )
                link.save()
                queryset.append(link)
            context = {
                "object_list": queryset,
                "query_id": query_obj.query_id,
                "p":query_obj.p,
                "user":user_p
            }
            return render(request, "news/home.html", context)
if(request.POST.get('query_id', None) is not None):
    query_id=request.POST.get('query_id', None)
    query_obj=Query.objects.get(pk=query_id)
    query_string=query_obj.query
    query_obj.p=query_obj.p+10
    query_obj.save()
    data = multi_scraping.scrape(search_dict, query_obj.p, query_obj.p+10, query_string)
    queryset = []
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        link = Link(scraping_id=str(query_obj),
                            isBlocked=row['isBlocked'],
                            published_Date=row['published'],
                            modified_date=row['update'],
                            language=row['language'],
                            search_engine=row['search_engine'],
                            source=row['source'],
                            source_url=row['source_url'],
                            title=row['title'],
                            transcript=row['transcript'],
                            url=row['url']
                            )
        link.save()
        queryset.append(link)
    context = {
        "object_list": queryset,
        "query_id": query_obj.query_id,
        "p": query_obj.p,
        "user": user_p
    }

    return render(request, "news/home.html", context)
```

Have you got any idea how to help?
anything would be appreciated!!!!!

Comment: Can you give us more context around the complex views? Regarding how to test them, you can implement automated unit tests via the testing framework. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to edit the question to make it clearer!

Answer (score 0):

> Since, you are going to use ***vue.js*** as your front-end with a
>   ***django backend*** so probably you need to make rest api's for the same.
>  Now django comeup with great features which includes rest
>   api imeplentation, but then you have to create your api views which
>   have to be serialized, so that the resultant rest api have either Json
>   or xml format. 
>  In your case, you have to convert the views, so
>   firstly need to convert your views to django rest serialized format.
>   So that you can handle the request which are coming from the frontend.

**Let's suppose below is your model :**

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

**So now, in order to get all the users data, you have to serialize the user object:**

```
class UserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields='__all__'
```

**Your output json data look like this:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 37,
        "username": "kevin morgan",
        "created_at": "2020-02-02T16:26:16.779900Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 38,
        "username": "john smith",
        "created_at": "2020-02-02T16:43:04.242829Z"
    }
]
```

You can read here for more [info](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)